# Why PackageInfo always comes back empty?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for developing a project with a generic trunk and two side branches for android and UWP.

The project is an app built in C#.

For some reason the PackageInfo always comes back empty. How can that be if there are loads of apps installed on my test phone? Including the one I'm looking for?

Any help would be much appreciated since I need this for work and I'm stuck with this problem for a few weeks now.

Thank you so much.

I'm trying to verify the presence of an app that my app calls through an intent. As a first step I'm trying to retrieve the PackageInfo for that purpose so that I can check for the package name inside it.

This code is from MyApp.Android\Services\HelperService.cs

```
public IList<ApplicationInfo> PM()
{
    IList<PackageInfo> lista = new List<PackageInfo>();
    PackageManager pm2 = new PM2();
    PackageInfoFlags flags = new PackageInfoFlags();
    IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = (IList<ApplicationInfo>)pm2.GetInstalledApplications(flags);
    return (List<ApplicationInfo>)packages;
}
```

On this same file I have the inherited method from the original abstract class:

```
public override IList<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledApplications([GeneratedEnum] PackageInfoFlags flags)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This is the interface

public interface IHelperService {
void OpenMPOS(string reference, string value);

```
bool ScreenOn(bool OnOff);

void ToastLong(string message, string title);

void ToastShort(string message, string title);

IList<ApplicationInfo> PM();
```

}

This is where I call the method to try and get the values, MyApp\Extensions\PaymentMethods.xaml.cs

```
IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = DependencyService.Get<Services.IHelperService>().PM();
```

Comment: If we rule out electromagnetic effects such as solar flares etc., my hunch is that you have made some programming error in that part of your project where you are retrieving the PackageInfo.

Comment: Right...after the joke are you ready to help? Like I said, I need this for work. How about instead of making fun of the situation you instead tell me what part of the code you would need to see to try to figure it out? This is the code: IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = (IList<ApplicationInfo>)pm2.GetInstalledApplications(flags);

Comment: Honestly, i first thought **you** were making some fun. You asked a question about a programming problem, without showing any code. You can't seriously expaect any help then. Then, don't put code into comments, but into the question. Also I suggest that you post a minimal reproducible example. Just a single statement won't tell us much. We don't know for instance the values of the variables you are using.

Comment: No my friend, it definetly wasn't a joke, but I see your point. Foolish of me to provide so few details. I also just learned how to add the code to the question. I'll edit it in a moment

Comment: Stackoverflow is a bit strict on the rules how to ask questions, so please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to write a good question, which attrackts the people with the right knowledge.

Comment: I understand. Like I said, it's my first time getting deep into Xamarin, so I still don't even have a grasp of how to ask. But thank you for your patience

Comment: I'm not really into Androin, but stupid question: Since you are searching for packages, shouldn't the call be `pm2.getInstalledPackages(...)`?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all, makes perfect sense. But no, shouldn't be lowercase because I'm using C#, not java.

Comment: It was not on the case, but on the name itself: GetInstalledPackages vs. GetInstalledModules.

Comment: I'm not using GetInstalledModules. You mean I should try GetInstalledPackages instead of GetInstalledApplications? I can't remember the reason right now but I did research it before and GetInstalledPackages seemed like the better option. I'll try to switch it and see what happens

Comment: As I said, I don't know about Android development, but first of all, it sounds reasonable to use a method to return packages when you want packages, and then [its documentation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/android.content.pm.packagemanager.getinstalledpackages?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) looks reasonable too.

Comment: BTW, perhaps you could improve your question by statng explicitly, whether your  variable `packages` contains `null` or an empty list.